# php erro with delete in table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've a problem to delete column of my base.

When I do the script php, nothing happens. If somebody can help me.

My database Tournament;

```
/*In the table Tournament */
INSERT INTO Tournament (nomTournament, nbPlayersMax, nbPlayersAct, dateStart, kindTournament_id, avancement, code, membre_mail)
VALUES ('MyTournamentFootball', '8', '0', NOW(), '2', '0', '6148', 'aa@gmail.com');

INSERT INTO Tournament (nomTournament, nbPlayersMax, nbPlayersAct, dateStart, kindTournament_id, Avancement, code, membre_mail)
VALUES ('MyTournamentFootball2', '4', '0', NOW(), '1', '0', '5691', 'aa@gmail.com');
```

and now my php code to delete :

```
<?php
session_start();

include ('config.php');

$nomTournament = 'MyTournamentFootball2';
$code = '5691';

// query the application data
$query = $handler->prepare("Delete from Tournament WHERE nomTournament = :nomTournament AND code = :code ;");

//bind the parameters
$query->bindParam(':nomTournament', $nomTournament, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':code', $code, PDO::PARAM_INT);

//execute the prepared statement
$query->execute();

?>
```

I know the code is simple but it doesn't work, so if you can help me.

Thanks

Michaël

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file to see any possible error and show us.

Comment: potential typo at line `$query = $handler->prepare("Delete from Tournament WHERE nomTournament = :nomTournament AND code = :code ;");` try removing semicolon inside prepare statements as `$query = $handler->prepare("Delete from Tournament WHERE nomTournament = :nomTournament AND code = :code ");`